# Noob query about relating newsgroup reference id to http location

Tags: newsgroup

I know this is not much programming related, but I would appreciate if someone could tell me on how to (if possible) a newsgroup reference id to a webpage.

Say, If the reference id of the newsgroup message is

```
<b6c92e67-0bbd-4dd1-be22-4357373fd19a@q35g2000vbi.googlegroups.com>
```

How do go to http page containing the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message-Ids don't have anything to do with web pages or URLs. They are generated as a unique identifier for each post.

You can search for them with Google, of course, [Google's Groups Search](http://groups.google.com/advanced_search) gives [results](http://groups.google.com/groups/search?as_umsgid=b6c92e67-0bbd-4dd1-be22-4357373fd19a%40q35g2000vbi.googlegroups.com).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My requirement is not that straightforward though. I think i  will have to dugg real deep into it.